# CakePHP 3 - Controller not found when setup thru routes.php

Tags: cakephp

Trying to play around with a test API. Based on the following routes setup, if I request `/v1/tests/index.json` I will get a JSON Object Response as expected, but if I request `/v1/test/index.json` I will get an error that TestController is missing. I have checked docs and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I expected the `$routes->connect('/test', [...]);` to work, but it is not. Any help in shining some light into this is appreciated.

```
<?php
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');
Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->prefix('v1', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->connect('/test', ['controller' => 'Tests', 'action' => 'index']);
        $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
    });

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');

});

Plugin::routes();
```

Comment: There are naming conventions for cakephp, you may try renaming your controller to TestController, but cakephp advises to use plural naming conventions

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know about those Cakephp conventions which is why I chose to use a route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit route set up matching `/v1/test/index.json`. Your:

```
$routes->connect('/test', ['controller' => 'Tests', 'action' => 'index']);
```

route will match `/v1/test` or `/v1/test.json|xml`, and that's all.

`/v1/test/index.json` will be catched by the fallback routes, and hence try to connect to the controller matching `test`, ie `TestController`.

Check out **[Cookbook > Routing > Connecting Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration)** more closely, you're doing what is shown in the `/government` example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to specify the action in the route connect?

```
$routes->connect('/test/index', ['controller' => 'Tests', 'action' => 'index']);
```